# SQLite errors using iPhone simulator/Possible permission issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm working on a new iPhone project and I'm running into problems with sqlite.  I've done this before on a different project and it worked just fine so I'm not sure exactly what is going on with this one.  I'm using the same code from before, but the situation is a little different.

First of all, I'm trying this time to use Unit Testing so I've created a Cocoa Unit Test Bundle, and I got that working correctly, then I wanted to make a Unit Test for my sqlite database.

The first thing run with this test is [self checkAndCreateDatabase] which is as follows:

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
        BOOL success;

        // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
        // of the database and to copy it over if required
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

        // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
        if(success) return;

        // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

        // Get the path to the database in the application package
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

        // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

        [fileManager release];
    }
```

Then I attempt to open the database with the following line:

```
int result = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database);
```

This fails everytime with error code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN, and databasePath is "/Users/labuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Documents/projectfusion.db3".

What is odd is that when I go to that directory, Documents/ isn't there, so if I create that, then it doesn't fail, BUT projectfusion.db3 then has a size of 0kb; the tables aren't there.  That makes any sqlite3_prepare_v2() fail, because the tables aren't there.  If I manually copy the projectfusion.db3 file to that directory before running, then it works just fine.

Is it because I'm doing this inside the unit tests and the scripts don't have permission or something?  Or is it possibly because I'm working on a school computer at my university and can't write to that directory? (I tried logging in as admin and it didn't work either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code given below,

I've set a macro called TEST so I don't have to keep commenting code out.

```
- (NSString *)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    #ifdef TEST
    documentsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
    #endif


    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DBNAME];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) { return writableDBPath;} ;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DBNAME];    
    #ifdef TEST
    defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"YOURDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    #endif

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return (defaultDBPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the database to your application bundle in xcode and then copy it to the applications Documents directory. You can get that path using

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
return basePath;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why that is any different from what I'm already doing.  I tried it by replacing my code above with 
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self applicationDocumentsDirectory], databaseName];
and the path that was returned was "/Users/labuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Documents/projectfusion.db3" which is the same as above.
I assume by "adding the database to your application bundle" you mean adding it as an existing file? I did that in my "Resources" directory.

Comment: It should return smth like this: /Users/max/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/C5178257-E12C-4088-BA2C-68E472458575/Documents   It is really strange. Ok, can you access your DB from the app bundle?

Comment: I looked in Finder under build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectFusion, "Show Package Contents" on ProjectFusion and it was in there.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok, one more question. Have you added DB to your unit tests bundle?

Comment: No I hadn't, I didn't think I had to because it has the whole ProjectFusion as a Direct Dependency.  But I tried to add it by (on the database file) right click->Get info->Targets and checking UnitTests as another target for it.  I got the same errors.

Comment: what is the value of databasePathFromApp?

Comment: When run from the UnitTests databasePathFromApp =  "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/projectfusion.db3"

I just tried to do the exact same things from the project and it runs just fine it looks like, and databasePathFromApp there = "/Users/labuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/C0783695-CB4D-4EA2-A1A9-DC7C8C797CEA/ProjectFusion.app/projectfusion.db3"

Comment: It would be a good idea to add NSError instance instead of nil to   [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
 so you could know if there is a problem during copying.

Comment: Hmmm, creating that NSError and calling localizedDescription yields "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"  And that makes sense since at that directory, there is no projectfusion.db3.  I don't understand completely how to get that file into that directory, I thought xcode would just handle it? Thanks for working through this...

Comment: don't use  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName] . You should use [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ofType:] if it returns nil, than your db is not in your test bundle.

Comment: I tried using pathForResources: ofType: (I like that, it seems a lot cleaner than the other way), and it returns nil.  I guess I need to understand how to add the db to the test bundle better.  I tried just setting its targets to both Project and UnitTests, tried deleting the reference to the file and re-adding it under resources and making sure both were checked, and tried deleting the file completely and adding it again, but all of those methods are making pathForResource return nil.  Am I adding it to the bundle incorrectly?